# No node for selector while using puppeteer on facebook messenger

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, automation, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to make a Facebook messenger api(kind of) for my home project.

Till now, I can login into my account using puppeteer successfully.

The real problem starts when I want to automate after logging in.

I can't click on any element.

---

**For Example**:

***I want to click on the little 'i' icon***:

[image]

***Then I copied the selector like***:

[image]

***I'm getting the following error in the conso*le**:

```
(node:4771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: #cch_feb64f1b00e628 > div._5742 > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > div > svg
(node:4771) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Code**:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function() {

    // This function is used to login into the account.
    async function login() {
        console.log('=====In Login=====');
        const email = '#email';
        const pass = '#pass';
        const submit = '#loginbutton';
        await page.waitFor(3000);
        await page.click(email);
        await page.waitFor(2000);
        await page.keyboard.type('not_a_real_email@mail.com');
        await page.waitFor(2000);
        await page.click(pass);
        await page.waitFor(2000);
        await page.keyboard.type('not_a_real_password');
        await page.waitFor(2000);
        await page.click(submit);
        return 0;
    }

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();


    page.on('load', () => console.log('=====Page loaded!====='));

    await page.goto('https://messenger.com');
    await login();
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitFor(3000); // I'm waiting just for safe side to make sure the element is loaded.

    // This is the line where the 'i' is clicked.
    // This is the line error occurs.
    await page.click(
        '#cch_feb64f1b00e628 > div._5742 > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > div > svg'
    );

})();
```

So, according to the above error, I know that the selector is wrong. Then what is the correct selector? Not only that, I'm getting same error when I tried it on other elements like the emoji element.

Comment: Is it possible that "cch_feb64f1b00e628" or "div._5742 " are dynamically generated and different every run?

Edit: It looks like you are trying to click on the svg element and not the parent anchor tag. Can you try the selector for that?

Comment: @cadmium I quickly checked. `#cch_feb64f1b00e628` is dynamically generated for every login. So, is there any other way to select it?

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but you may be able to select it with '[data-testid="info_panel_button"]'. That should return the anchor button.

Comment: @cadmium The 3 elements(voice call, video call, "i" ) are wrapped inside `<ul>` tag and the selector of that is generated dynamically. So, is there any way to get the element other than that selector? Like using a regex to get that element.

Comment: @cadmium How can I access `[data-testid="info_panel_button"]` through puppeteer?

Comment: Good question. Give this a try: `await page.click(
        '[data-testid="info_panel_button"]'
    );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the selector you are using is dynamically generated at runtime and changes every page refresh. Assuming you want to click on just the I (info) button, the following click/selector using the data-testid works for me:

```
await page.click(
    '[data-testid="info_panel_button"]'
);
```

If you are wanting to test the other icons at the top, they unfortunately don't seem to have the same data-testid, meaning they would be more challenging to select.

Full example

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function() {

  // This function is used to login into the account.
  async function login() {
    console.log('=====In Login=====');
    const email = '#email';
    const pass = '#pass';
    const submit = '#loginbutton';
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.click(email);
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.keyboard.type('not_a_real_email@mail.com');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.click(pass);
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.keyboard.type('not_a_real_password');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.click(submit);
    return 0;
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();


  page.on('load', () => console.log('=====Page loaded!====='));

  await page.goto('https://messenger.com');
  await login();
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.waitFor(3000); // I'm waiting just for safe side to make sure the element is loaded.

  // This is the line where the 'i' is clicked.
  // This is the line error occurs.
  await page.click(
      '[data-testid="info_panel_button"]'
  );})();
```

Comment: But can't we use `title` attribute to select a tag? As you mentioned, the above works great for "i" but what about other tags. Can we select the tags based on other attributes like the `title` etc? I tried on `title` but it failed with an error. Is there any other way? Or should I get down into `page.evaluate()` to iterate over tags and find the title attribute myself? I think using `document.getElementxxxx()` method is one of the ways to access all the elements.

Comment: Yes, you can use title (or most any other element) `await page.click(''[title="Start a video chat"]'')` should work. The downside with those particular buttons, is that they spawn a new window. I'm not sure how to deal with that in puppeteer yet, tbh.

Comment: I think I have to try it and post it as a new question. Thanks for your answer. It really helped for my project.

Comment: I again read the puppeteer api and found about `page.$$(selector)`. To prevent opening in a new window, we can use `let elements = await page.$$('[title="Conversation information"]');` and then `elements[0].click({ button: 'left' });`